# EHCache doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I've set up ehcache on our Java application, which uses Spring and Hibernate.
However, when I run Junit tests and print the stats, it seems there is nothing in cache:

OUTPUT OF CACHE MANAGER STATS ON EVERY CACHE:

COM.****.SERVICES.CLARITY.DOMAIN.ACTIONITEM.BYRESOURCEUNIQUENAME: 
getCacheHits: 0
getCacheMisses: 0
getObjectCount: 0

COM.****.SERVICES.CLARITY.DOMAIN.ACTIONITEM: 
getCacheHits: 0
getCacheMisses: 0
getObjectCount: 0

COM.****.SERVICES.CLARITY.DOMAIN.RESOURCE: 
getCacheHits: 0
getCacheMisses: 0
getObjectCount: 0

CONTENT OF THE MAPPING FILE (ONLY PARTS, TOO BIG TO PASTE ALL):

```
<class name="ActionItem" table="CAL_ACTION_ITEMS" mutable="false" lazy="false" >
<cache region="com.****.services.clarity.domain.ActionItem" usage="read-only" include="all" />
```

[...]

```
<query name="byResourceUniqueName" cacheable="true" cache-region="com.****.services.clarity.domain.ActionItem.byResourceUniqueName" read-only="true">
    FROM ActionItem WHERE id IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT actionItemId FROM ActionItemAssignee as aia WHERE assigneeId IN (
            SELECT userId FROM Resource WHERE uniqueName = :uniqueName
        )
    )
    ORDER BY dueDate
</query>
```

CONTENT OF EHCACHE.XML:

```
<cache
    name="com.****.services.clarity.domain.ActionItem"
    maxElementsInMemory="2000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="600" overflowToDisk="false" />

<cache
    name="com.****.services.clarity.domain.ActionItem.byResourceUniqueName"
    maxElementsInMemory="2000" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
    timeToLiveSeconds="60" overflowToDisk="false" />

<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="200" eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" overflowToDisk="true"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />
```

HIBERNATE CONFIG:

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.format_sql=true
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
            hibernate.cache.provider_class=net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
            hibernate.show_sql=true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any ideas on how to populate the cache ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the items get populated to the cache by Hibernate automatically.

One thing I noticed in your configuration is that you didn't enable the statistics. Add the property

```
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

to your session factory's configuration and see, if numbers occur in your output.

Answer (score 1):

yeah,when you use second cache in hibernate , when you will query you must set like this:

```
Query q=....
q.setCacheable(tre);
```

if you Spring you must write like this

```
getHibernateTemplate().setCacheQueries(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure cache usage for `ActionItem`s should be `read-only`? How are the those items populated initially? And, even if that is correct for your business model, consider changing it to `nonstrict-read-write`, to see if it changes anything in your test.

Then, have you tried executing `byResourceUniqueName` query with caching enabled:

```
Query q = getSession().getNamedQuery("byResourceUniqueName");
q.setCacheable(true);
List result = q.list();
```

Even though `cacheable` parameter should influence only caching of the result set of the query, again, see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider instead of the net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider